# How to fix "library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.0.0.dylib" when installing Rust on macOS?

Tags: rust

I was trying to install Rust on my Mac with the command `curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh`, but received the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/libssh2.1.dylib
  Reason: image not found
[1]    5499 abort      curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | 
       5500 done       sh
```

What should I do?

Comment: Your Conda installation is messing with Rust finding the correct resources because it’s misconfigured. Step 1 should be to try to fix the Conda environment (specifically, libssh2). If that fails, disable the Conda environment or, if that’s not enough, uninstall it (obviously this is a drastic suggestion and you might not want to do that).

Comment: @KonradRudolph do you mind elaborating on what you meant by "fixing the Conda environment"? Thanks!

Comment: I can only speculate but you could try reinstalling libssh2 and libssl in the Conda environment, since that (at minimum) seems to be broken. Better yet, try uninstalling libssh2, since it’s apparently labelled as “broken” in Conda.

Comment: @KonradRudolph uninstalling Anaconda fixed the issue, thank you!